# printf() - how to add leading zeroes + padding

Tags: c, printf

I want to pad a column so it's 8 characters wide, and make integers left-aligned with at most one leading zero like this:

```
[00      ]
[01      ]
[07      ]
[11      ]
[14      ]
```

I know how to add the leading zeroes (`printf("%02d\n", integer)`) or the padding (`printf("%-8d\n", integer)`), but I don't know how to combine the two. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Does `printf("%-08.2d\n", integer)` not work?  Or have I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This _seems_ to work as intended, but gives following warnings at compilation: `test.c:122:10: warning: '0' flag ignored with '-' flag in gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]` and `test.c:122:10: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and ‘%d’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]`

Comment: A trivial, yet less clean approach would be to first prepare the two strings and then concatenate them. i.e., `sprintf("%02d", integer, number_char_array)`, then create another string of spaces, i.e., `padding_char_array`, sized `8 - strlen(number_char_array)`. Then use `printf("[%s%s]", number_char_array, padding_char_array)`

Comment: @G.M. The `-` and `0` flags can't be combined usefully (and GCC 8.3.0 warns about that).  But `printf("[%-8.2d]\n", integer)` does the required job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed, I missed that.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: stitch123, when `integer` exceeds 8 digits, what should be printed?  How should negative values appear?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Negative values won't appear and we can assume that 8 digits won't be exceeded. I think the accepted answer is the most appropriate solution to what I was looking for.

Comment: @stitch123 Good you found a solution for your limited application.  Tip: be warned that in real life, input is rarely well behaved and functionality should be defined for all possible inputs.  Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the minimum field width (`8`) and the precision (`.2`) and left-justification (`-`) — see [`fprintf()`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) — like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 0, 1, 7, 11, 14, 314159 };
    enum { NUM_ARRAY = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ARRAY; i++)
        printf("[%-8.2d]\n", array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (on macOS 12.3):

```
[00      ]
[01      ]
[07      ]
[11      ]
[14      ]
[314159  ]
```

This seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When adding the leading zeroes and assuming that the numbers do not exceed the resulting width (in this case 2, i.e. that the integers are between -9 and 99), the width is constant so the padding can be inserted as a fixed number of spaces:

```
   printf("[%02d      ]\n", integer);
```

Comment: It's not guaranteed not to go over 99, but it's very unlikely (should've specified that in the original post, sorry), so I might go with this solution in the end!